# ZFS convert from RAID10 to RAID1 (mirror)

Tags: raid, zfs

I have a ZFS array with 4x4TB, configured in a RAID10 so that it's two mirrors striped together.  I want to convert this to 2x10TB, so I want only one mirror that consists of the two disks.

Is there a way to do this in-place?  If needed, I can use the `com.delphix:device_removal` feature, but I would prefer not to.